# The Duffing oscillator - Discrete Jacobian matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, jacobian

Assume I have the Duffing oscillator (driven with frequency $\omega$)

$$\frac{dx^2}{dt^2} = x-x^3-\beta v+ \alpha \cos(\omega t)$$
 The dynamics in continuous time is given by
$$\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}=f(\vec{x})$$ 
where in this case $\vec{x}=x,v,\varphi$.

Assuming I know $f(\vec{x})$ for Duffing (and I do), I can calculate the Jacobian matrix using
$$J=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}$$

Say that $\phi_t(\vec{x})$ is the flow function of the dynamical system, and I define the Poincare section at $\varphi=0$. Two questions:

1) How does one  actually show that  $P=\phi_{2\pi/\omega}$ is the Poincare map (a.k.a. return map) on this section?

2) How can $detK$ where $K=\frac{\partial{P}}{\partial{x}}$ be calculated from $J$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be great if you actually wrote out your version of Duffing's because then people would be able to identify your variables,  Cheers!

Comment: Well, no action on your part yet . . . can't watch your question much longer . . . do drop me a message if you decide to include your vs. of Duffs.  Cheers!

Comment: My apologies. I just updated it.

Comment: Is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289932/poincare-map-of-a-periodically-driven-system/2290170#2290170) an explanation for Poincaré map that you are looking for?

Comment: @Evgeny Yes, it certainly answers my first question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much for adding your version of Duffing's.  Cheers!